# How to specify a container id on managed instance groups

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gce-instance-group

When accessing an instance from a managed instance group on GCE, the deployed app container has a random container id (like c948a5850b6c) instead of a named one (like app).
Is there a way to specify an id to simplify accessing the container?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can only defined the Container Name but no the Container ID, but you can refer directly to his Container Name, so there is no need to refer to the Container ID.

[More details](https://www.tecmint.com/name-docker-containers/)

Comment: Yes, the thing is the container name is long. Since we access the container frequently, it becomes tedious. Thanks for the answer